# Django Forms Customization

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have a page that displays products that have been ordered and I want to give the user the ability to leave a review on their products which have been ordered. I have a review model as well, but when rendering the form it will list all of the products available on the website when I want only the products the customer has ordered to display. Is this possible? I am unsure how to accomplish this with django.

edit: if it makes more sense due to my bad explanation, I want the select options to be limited to only what the user has ordered

This is the form

```
class ReviewForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Review
        exclude = ['user', 'date']
        widgets = {
            'product': forms.Select(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control'
            }),
            'rating': forms.NumberInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': '5.0..'
            }),
            'comment': forms.Textarea(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control'
            })
        }
```

This is the view with the get request only

```
class MyOrdersView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            order = ShoppingCartOrder.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, ordered=True)
            form = ReviewForm()
            context = {
                'object': order,
                'form': form
            }
            return render(request, 'my_site/my_orders.html', context)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            messages.warning(request, 'You do not have any orders')
            return redirect('all_products')
```

And if needed this is how I am displaying the form on the page

```
    <div class="container w-25 mb-5">
        <form>
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% for field in form %}
            <div class="form-group px-3 my-3">
            {{ field.label_tag }}
            {{ field }}
            {{ field.help_text }}
            {{ field.errors }}
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
          </form>
    </div>
```

this is the review model

```
class Review(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    rating = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1, validators=[MinValueValidator(Decimal('0.1'))])
    comment = models.TextField(validators=[MinLengthValidator(10)])
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show your Review model, but we can assume that you have a foreign key field towards Product.

Django renders foreign key fields as [MultipleChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield), by default. Looking at the documentation, MultipleChoiceField has a `queryset` parameter. You can use this to filter the products to show on the form.

Based on the code you provided, you can set the query set from the `__init__` method of the form:

```
class ReviewForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['product'].queryset = ...

    class Meta:
        ...
```

Comment: oops sorry about that, will update with my model but your assumption was correct!

Comment: thank you for the help, I was able to figure it out based on your solution but now have a different issue haha